Android emulator not staring on AMD Ryzen 5500U. Keep showing starting up
ATTACHED SCREENSHOT OF THE ISSUE I'm developing a react native app in my AMD processor laptop. But the emulator is not booting up. It keeps showing starting up. Windows HyperVisor platform is enabled and virtualization is also enabled. Please help.
Tried to re install android studio earlier versions but no luck.

There's nothing at all? Include screenshots if possible of what you are seeing and any errors or messages that you encounter.

Attached screenshot

I was having the same issue, although I'm on Intel (with an AMD GPU). I went into the SDK Manager of Android Studio, installed everything within SDK Tools (may not be necessary but just wanted to try all avenues to solve it) and made sure to update everything in there as well. After that, the emulator booted up without a hitch.
It was a fresh install of Android Studio that I had to tinker with to get it to work.
